# Proving that the co-efficients of any Laurent series can be expressed in terms of a single line integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if I have a Laurent series $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k(z - z_0)^k$$

Which is convergent on an annulus between $R_1$ and $R_2$,
then for any $R_1 < R < R_2$, $a_k$ can be expressed as the integral
$$a_k = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|\zeta-z_0| = R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z_0)^{k+1}}d\zeta$$

I already have that since $f(\zeta)$ itself can be expressed as the Laurent series, I can rewrite the right hand side of the above equation as

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|\zeta-z_0| = R}\frac{\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}a_j(\zeta - z_0)^j}{(\zeta - z_0)^{k+1}}d\zeta $$

Then I can split up the Laurent series in the numerator into its principle part plus its part with positive powers. And I can exchange the series and integral signs since the above is also uniformly convergent, so I get:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\Bigg(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|\zeta-z_0| = R}\frac{(\zeta - z_0)^{-j}}{(\zeta - z_0)^{k+1}}d\zeta\Bigg)a_{-j} \:+\: \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\Bigg(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|\zeta-z_0| = R}\frac{(\zeta - z_0)^{j}}{(\zeta - z_0)^{k+1}}d\zeta\Bigg)a_{j}$$

I noticed that this expression is starting to look a bit like a Laurent series in the form

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\Bigg(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|\zeta-z_0| = R_2}\frac{f(\zeta - z_0)}{(\zeta - z_0)^{j+1}}d\zeta\Bigg)a_{-j} \:+\: \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\Bigg(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|\zeta-z_0| = R_1}\frac{f(\zeta - z_0)}{(\zeta - z_0)^{j+1}}d\zeta\Bigg)a_{j}$$

But I don't know I would make those equivalent, or how making them equivalent would even help me. I would appreciate a hint on how to proceed from here.